# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, types, typeerror, nonetype

I wrote rock-paper-scissor game with python and I have error which I can't solve. please help.

```
 import random 
p1 = random.randint(0, 2)
def choosing():
    p = int(input("Rock: 0; Paper: 1; scissor: 2:"))
    if p < 0 or p > 2:
       print("\nPlease enter valid value")
       choosing()
    else:
      return int(p)
p2 = choosing()

print ("\n" + str(p1))
if p1 == p2:
  print("DRAW!!")
elif p2 - p1 == 1 or p1 - p2 == 2:
  print("YOU WON!!")
elif p1 - p2 == 1 or p2 - p1 == 2:
  print("YOU LOSE!!")
```

Error says

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 15, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

and error comes only when I input valid value after entering invalid value

Comment: You missed a return in line 7

Comment: Recursion seems a little overkill for asking input.

Comment: I have also another problem, when code is running in online interpreter everything is OK but when running in linux terminal I have error    
 `./paper.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token '('
./paper.py: line 2: 'p1 = random.randint(0, 2)'`

Answer (score 2):

When you call `choosing()` again, you don't return its value, so it returns `None`.  Change the line:

```
choosing()
```

to:

```
return choosing()
```

This would be better as a loop than as a recursive call, in my opinion.

Comment: Not only better in Python but likely _proper_, given the lack of tail-call optimization in most (all?) Python interpreters, and the smallish stacks.

Comment: If someone takes 1,000 tries to enter a valid response, the resulting `RecursionError` is not entirely undeserved.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if you do not explicitly return a value it will return a default of `None` type. You can fix this by adding a returning the function call `choosing()`:

```
def choosing():
    p = int(input("Rock: 0; Paper: 1; scissor: 2:"))
    if p < 0 or p > 2:
       print("\nPlease enter valid value")
       return choosing()
    else:
      return int(p)
```

Also, I agree with @Kindall, recursion here seems like an overkill for simply asking for input.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens in casting the non-number input to int

```
p = int(input("Rock: 0; Paper: 1; scissor: 2:"))
```

which can be handled with try-catch. I also feel strange to use recursion in choosing() function. I would do the function as

```
def choosing():
    while True:
        try:
            p = int(input("Rock: 0; Paper: 1; scissor: 2:"))
            if p < 0 or p > 2:
                print("\nPlease enter valid value")
            else:
                return p
        except ValueError:
            print("\nPlease enter valid value")
```